# How the right way to get input value from ejs.file

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get input value but I always get 'undefined'.

```
    <form action="/nivelamento" method="POST">
          <h2><%= quizzes[pos].question %></h2>
          <input type="radio" name='options' value="A" checked><%= chA %>
          <input type="radio" name='options' value="B" checked><%= chB %>
          <input type="radio" name='options' value="C" checked><%= chC %>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Submit Answer</button>
    </form>
```

My app.js

```
app.post('/nivelamento', (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body.name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You get undefined because of you named input as "options" and you're trying to access "name" property. You need to write

> req.body.options

***(but you named inputs with this key multiple times and you will get values as an array)***