# Nodejs send variable to ejs page

Tags: node.js, variables, ejs

I have a question, is it possible to define a variable in nodejs and then use it in the ejs page? So for example  var newOne = "Yes" in nodejs. And then i want to use this variable in the ejs page to check if that variable is equal to yes, in its script tag. I tried this but it always ends up as undefined variable.

How does one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Suppose you have a variable in node

```
var newOne = "Yes";
```

you can use the variable in ejs, like the following.

1. You need to send the variable into the view during the rendering like below

```
res.render('/nameOfTheRoute', {
  newOneInView : newOne
});
```

2. Then you can check conditions in ejs by accessing newOneInView like below

```
<%if (newOneInView == "Yes") { %>
// Do something
<% } %>
```

Comment: Quick other question @arulmani venkatesh  is there also a way to do this reverse? So that i would set up a variable in the ejs file and use it in nodejs?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633393/how-the-right-way-to-get-input-value-from-ejs-file

Comment: Thanks, one more question @arulmani venkatesh how do i make this script run when the page is loading in. Because right now its seems that it wont run by it self.

Comment: ejs scripts are initiated by page load. So this shld work when the page is called in

Comment: And what if would want to change the variable value from the client side ? @arulmani venkatesh

Comment: Attach it to an input field in html

Comment: And how could you change the actual value of the variable? @Venkatesh A